# phpunit-skelgen : No test file generated

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I try to use phpunit-skelgen

In the doc, it is written

> When you are using the skeleton generator to generate code based on a class that is declared in a namespace you have to provide the qualified name of the class as well as the path to the source file it is declared in.
>
> For instance, for a class Calculator that is declared in the project namespace you need to invoke the skeleton generator like this:
>
> phpunit-skelgen --test -- "project\Calculator" Calculator.php
>   PHPUnit Skeleton Generator 1.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Wrote skeleton for "project\CalculatorTest" to "/home/sb/CalculatorTest.php".

I'm working with symfony 2
My class is like this :

```
<?php
// src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Security/User/MyUserProvider.php

namespace Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

use Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUser;

class MyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    // public functions ...
}
```

I've tried to run, from my application base directory

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider" "Absolute\Path\to\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider.php"
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider" Absolute\Path\to\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider.php
phpunit-skelgen --test -- Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider Absolute\Path\to\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider.php
```

even

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider" MyUserProvider.php
```

and

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- MyUserProvider MyUserProvider.php
```

from Absolute\Path\to\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\

```
phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider" MyUserProvider.php
```

The output is always

```
PHPUnit Skeleton Generator 1.2.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Nothing more.
Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Instead of updating your question to include the answer and add a useless [SOLVED] in your title, you should better post an answer an accept it. This is the way Stackoverflow works to define a question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply forgot the bootstrap

```
phpunit-skelgen --bootstrap app\bootstrap.php.cache --test -- "Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider" "E:\path\to\app\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider.php"
```

Comment: Hi @fatbob, it is very useful for me with ```Netbeans 8.0.1``` to configure and use ```bootstrap.php.cache```